# Calculate percentage of all alliances in year in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe that looks like (real frame has years from 1990 to 2020):

| Year | Chains_Normalize | Alliance_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | 0.000 | Gaint Inc |
| 1990 | 0.000 | Kell Inc |
| 1990 | 0.000 | New Corp |
| 1991 | 13.222 | Sad Corp |
| 1991 | 18.152 | Second Corp |
| 1991 | 16.333 | Shin Inc |
| 1992 | 19.212 | No inc |
| 1992 | 0.000 | Third inc |
| 1992 | 14.332 | Fourth inc |

I have to calculate the percentage of alliances in every year if Chains_Normalize is not 0. (The idea is to count what percentage of all alliances from dataframe includes every year)

The result will look like this:

```
Year  Percentage
1990  0.000
1991  33.333
1992  22.222
```

1990 has all zero alliances and it's percentage is 0.

1991 has 3 no-zero alliances and (3/9)*100 = 33.333

1992 has 2 no-zero alliances and (2/9)*100 = 22.222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply count the non-zeros per year and then divide by the length of `df` and multiply by 100 (which you already do manually with `(N/9)*100`):

```
>>> df['Chains_Normalize'].ne(0).groupby(df['Year']).sum() / len(df) * 100
Year
1990     0.000000
1991    33.333333
1992    22.222222
Name: Chains_Normalize, dtype: float64
```

this works because `df['Chains_Normalize'].ne(0)` returns a series of booleans where the alliances are non-zero, that you can then sum:

```
>>> df['Chains_Normalize'].ne(0)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
Name: Chains_Normalize, dtype: bool
```